# How do I get specific function suggestions in VSCode for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am learning flutter and been using the ctrl+space shortcut to get suggestions of what the widget/function needs. But recently I noticed that for specific inbult function I am getting all the suggestions rather than the Function specific ones. I am in the Root project and `pubsec.yaml` and every other configuration is present. Here is the screenshot:

What I am getting:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

I am on VScode and tried to tinger some settings and installing multiple extensions but that didn't help. Also tried to find info in web but got some related to Eclipse and other IDE.
This is the current info about the VSCode I am using:

- Version: 1.78.2 (user setup)
- Date: 2023-05-10T14:39:26.248Z
- Electron: 22.5.2
- Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
- Node.js: 16.17.1
- V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
- Sandboxed: Yes

Please suggest any way to fix this. Trying new things becomes a little harder when every suggestions throws up all at once.

Comment: try to have Flutter, Flutter Widget Snippets and Awesome Flutter snippets extension

Comment: I have those Extensions,still I am not getting the specific suggestions.

Comment: please provide steps to reproduce this issue, including copying and pasting the output of the `Help: About` command (run in the command palette) into your question post, and minimal example code (in the form of a textual code block) that can be used.

Comment: you can try reinstalling the IDE

Comment: @user I didn't got what you mean by the `Help:About` command.Sorry I am new to these stuffs.Will be helpful if you can elaborate a little.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette